# Three JS face normals in scaled mesh

Tags: three.js

When I scale imported OBJ model, the face normals are not scaled.

Is there a method to correct face normals on a scaled mesh?

Actually using `face.normal.multiplyScalar ( scale );` but this is not the ideal solution.

Comment: Normals must have unit length. What are you scaling them for?

Comment: I need face normals of each face relative to scale. I'm scaling models relatively by the DB values, most of them by hundreds of thousands.

Comment: Normals must have unit length.